# What is the proper tag name for tempo indications/directions/instructions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm writing because of the question [What's the difference between "con brio" and "con fuoco"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/80033/2257).

The tags "conbrio" and "confuoco" (which should be "con-brio" and "con-fuoco") are almost certainly too specific.  I do not see a tag for tempo indications or directions.  There is a "tempo" tag, but "con brio" and "con fuoco" are more precisely thought of as instructions about a piece's *affect* or *character* than its tempo.

I'm therefore soliciting suggestions for a tag name to encompass the directions that appear at the beginning of a musical score, which normally but not always specify the speed of the piece.

In the absence of a better suggestion, I will probably retag the question with "tempo-indication."

Comment: Is [tag:terminology] too inexact?

Comment: @Richard no, and it should certainly be used (I see someone else has already retagged the question).  Perhaps I should use that tag to ask if there's a less tempo-centric term for *tempo indication* that would acknowledge that these instructions sometimes have no direct bearing on tempo.  But it is somewhat *broader* than what I had in mind.  Maybe there's no need for a more specific tag, though.

Answer (score 1):

### Notation

There may be something more specific, but this is the big category for these questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think User Richard hit it right on the money in the comment section with ***terminology***. Perhaps ***performance-text***, which doesn't exist, but might be helpful...? I wouldn't want anything too specific, but terminology seems to pretty much cover it.